# Троичная логика в SQL

Tags: sql

В SQL фигурирует значение `NULL`, функциональная роль которого заключается в обозначении отсутствующих или неизвестных данных. Для этого значения установлены правила выполнения предикатов, которые при участии `NULL` возвращают не `TRUE` или `FALSE`, а `UNKNOWN`, что вполне соответствует бытовой логике: если одно из данных отсутствует, то результат операции нам неизвестен. Но есть ли у такого расширения до троичной логики функциональная роль, или на практике, если заменить все `UNKNOW` на `FALSE`, то мы не заметим разницы? Насколько я знаю, от предиката требуется вернуть `TRUE`, чтобы произошло некоторое действие. Быть может, в разных реализациях это устроенно по разному? Буду рад каким-нибудь рассказам или ссылкам на эту тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если заменить **Unknown** значения на **False**, то возникают неоднозначности:

- **Not False** = **True**, но **Not Unknown** != **True**.
- Из предыдущего следует **False or Not False** = **True**. Но
  **Unknown or Not Unknown** != **True**. *Не всегда любое высказывание либо истинно, либо ложно*.

Например:

Выведем продукты, которые стоят больше не больше 100:

```
select * from products t1 where not t1.price>100
```

В этом вариант в результат не попадут строки, в которых стоимость(`price`) не известна. Если же **Unknown** заменить на **False**, то в  результат попали бы строчки, для которых стоимость не известна, что не соответствует истине.

**PS**

Справедливости ради надо сказать, что в данном примере запрос можно переписать для правильной работы в случае **FALSE** = **Unknown**

```
select * from products t1 where t1.price<=100
```

Comment: Все-таки Unknown, а не Null. И в SQL логические значения нельзя сравнивать.

Comment: @IDrakonl, спасибо за ответ. По поводу ответа: заменять на FALSE предлагается не NULL (что невозможно хотя бы по причинам типа данных), а UNKNOW как результат выполнения предиката. Непонятно что означает предложение заменить в price NULL на FALSE, это же  real.

То есть вопрос не о разнице между троичной и двоичной логиками, а о функциональном значении троичной логики в SQL.

Comment: @PavelMayorov в случае `Oracle sql` UNKNOW и NULL - это одно и то же. Про сравнение справедливо. Я плохо выразил свои мысли, сейчас исправлю

Comment: @lDrakonl Но ANSI SQL их различает, а на вопросе стоит общая метка.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а в рамках этого вопроса есть какая то разница в действительности? Я могу заменить null на unknown в нужных местах, если для этого существует объективная причина

Comment: @lDrakonl, Ваши примеры просто не отвечают на поставленный вопрос. Правильно они выглядят так: X = X - это TRUE, NULL = NULL - это UNKNOWN, но никакого изменения функциональной структуры от замены этого UNKNOWN на FALSE Ваш пример не высвечивает.

Comment: @AkariGale кажется я изначально не совсем понял вопрос. Но разве часть про отрицание не отвечает на него? `NOT UNKNOWN!=TRUE`, а `NOT FALSE=TRUE`

Comment: Понятно, что если изменить UNKNOW на FALSE, то логика станет беднее, а некоторые истинные соотношения перейдут в ложные. Но что будет, если заменить конкретно в SQL все UNKNOWN на FALSE. Например считать, что NULL > 0 -> FALSE. 

Ваш пример про замену касался price, но я говорю не о первичных данных, а о результатах выполнения предикатов.

Comment: Что подразумевается под словами "в результатах выполнения предикатов" ? `price > 100` - это и есть предикат. И `not price >100` это тоже предикат. В общем я тогда не понимаю Ваш вопрос =(

Comment: @lDrakonl, прошу прощения, теперь я невнимательно прочел Ваш пример, из-за того что в начале UNKNOWN обозначался как NULL. Да, я уловил разницу, спасибо.

Comment: @AkariGale на самом деле мне не понятна причина добавления `UNKNOWN`.  В троичной логике 3 значения - `true, false, null`. Предикаты на этих значениях возвращают в результате одно из этих же  значений. Похоже на то, что `unknown` вводится просто для удобства

Answer (score 2):

При выборке данных необходимо, чтобы предикат был `TRUE`.

При вставке данных в таблицу предикат не должен быть `FALSE` (т.е. `TRUE` или `UNKNOWN`).